# How to check if a post has new comments?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, real-time

To check if there are any new comments on a post I have to:

1. Fetch all the posts on a page including the comments.
2. Compare the just pulled data to the data stored locally.

Is there a more efficient way to do this? For example, checking if post objects are changed since a given date?

Answer (score 0):

You can check updated_time of current post - the time of the last comment on this post.

Comment: Are you sure this works? 

A post says:
      "created_time": "2011-11-10T23:13:20+0000", 
      "updated_time": "2011-11-10T23:13:20+0000", 
      "likes": {
        "data": [
          {
            "name": "Horst Kutscher", 
            "id": "1820902975"
          }
        ], 
        "count": 547
      }, 
      "comments": {
        "count": 199
      }
The updated_date and created_date are the same, but the post got 199 comments

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

- check post total comments number (if it has), or
- check and compare the last comments (time or hash)

Comment: That's what i'm doing now. But it would be nice to get a list with changes instead of get every post for every page my application is registered to.